# TEdit and focus selection works different depending on Show/showmodal

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

When switching focus between `TEdits`, the selection changes depending on the way you show the form.
When you show it with `Form.show`, and swith between two `TEdits`, the text is selected.
When you show the form with `Form.Showmodal`, And switch between, the cursor is at the end of the newly focused `TEdit`

reproduce :
Create a new form with 2 `TEdits`, type some text in both. Then switch between both `TEdits`, the whole text is selected, but when I show the form with Modal, The caret is positioned behind the text.

Why is there a difference in functionality? And where can I change it.

I found the code responsible :

```
procedure TStyledEdit.DoEnter;
var
  Form: TCommonCustomForm;
begin
  inherited;
  Form := TCommonCustomForm(Root);
  if not Model.IsReadOnly and Model.InputSupport and not FTextService.HasMarkedText and
    ((Form = nil) 
//next part returns false
or (Form.FormState * [TFmxFormState.Showing] = [TFmxFormState.Showing]) or
    (Form.FormState = [TFmxFormState.Engaged])) then
    Edit.SelectAll
  else
  begin
    UpdateSelectionPointPositions;
    UpdateCaretPosition;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce issue that you describe. Behavior completely the same. XE8.

Answer (score 0):

DoEnter is a protected method and as such you can override with your own method if you wish.

You can either do this the classic way by creating your own descendant class (with a different type name) or you can use the so-called interceptor classes as described in this link: [interceptor classes](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2009/qt/interceptor.htm).

I believed that you need to extend the if clause like this (but not tested - sorry)

```
  if not Model.IsReadOnly and Model.InputSupport and not FTextService.HasMarkedText and
    ((Form = nil) 
     or (Form.FormState * [TFmxFormState.Showing] = [TFmxFormState.Showing]) 
     or (Form.FormState * [TFmxFormState.Modal] = [TFmxFormState.Modal]) 
     or (Form.FormState = [TFmxFormState.Engaged])) then
```

Comment: Maybe this was not clear in the question, but the code that runs is from TStyledEdit, wich fires when you focus a TEdit. I cannot intercept the code of the TSyledEdit, because my control is a TEdit class, when I create an interceptor class for TEdit and do ´SelectAll` the text is not highlighted.

Comment: OK, I have Delphi XE7, I will try to reproduce and get back to you.

Comment: I have built and tested as you suggested in XE7 and can find no difference in behaviour. So something else must be different. Can you post your full code, including anything you have set for the TEdit properties and the TabOrder properties and I will look at it again. Also any Styles you have set.